# How can I force my footer to stick to the bottom of any page in CSS?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

This is my code:

```
#footer {
   font-size: 10px;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   background:#ffffff;
}
```

I've no idea what is wrong with this - can anyone help?

EDIT: For some more clarity on what's wrong: The footer is displayed on the bottom as expected when the page loads. However, when the web page's height is > than the dimensions on the screen such that a scroll bar appears, the footer stays in that same location. That is to say, when the height of the page is <= 100%, the footer is at the bottom. However, when the page height is >100%, the footer is NOT at the bottom of that page, but at the bottom of the visible screen instead.

**EDIT: Surprisingly, none of the solutions below worked. I ended up implementing a sidebar instead.**

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: What SLaks is saying is: this is a poor question, as you have not described either the results you want nor the results you are getting. What you have written is valid CSS code, that is all I can tell you. Also, as noted above, this question has been asked and answered previously.

Answer (score 28):

You're probably looking for [this example](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Your content here
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    Your footer here
</div>
```

## CSS:

For a 142-pixel footer

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Comment: What about variable height footers?

Comment: @DustinGraham: You'll need to use flex, and move the scrollbar to the content

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
position: fixed;  
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: This will put the footer at the bottom of the window, but not at the bottom of the page (if the page is higher than the window)...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question, came here looking for an answer, didn't find it, then tried a few experiments on my own, and finally got **the solution**:

```css
#body {
  overflow-y: 0 auto;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh; left: 0;
  margin-top: -100px;
  width: 100%; height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <span>Some dummy Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper is the rest of your page.  The negative/positive margin/height values are where the magic happens.

```
.wrapper 
  {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
  }
.footer, .push 
  {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
  }
```

Comment: What is the push class for?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use position: absolute; for any footer as the page will change in height. If it is absolute then your footer will not move with the page height.

You want to use ryan fait's method.

Although I would personally do it like this;

```
.wrap {margin: auto; width: 980px;}
#content {min-height: 600px;}
#footer {height: 300px;}

<div class="wrap">
<div id="content">
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<div class="wrap">
</div>
</div>
```

This way you don't have to mess around with negative margins and padding. Also this can easily be a part of html5 changing #footer to

```
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Where did you get 300px and 600px? Not very generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer { clear:both; position:fixed; width:100%; height:50px; bottom:0; background:black;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it caused my footer to stay at the bottom.

```
.footer2{
background-color:#606060 ;
color: #ffffff;
height: 30px;
bottom:0px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer-small, .push {
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 5px;
    clear:both;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

this is also working for me....

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find a solution, as none of the suggested achieved what I wanted:

- If there is to less content, stay at the bottom of the page, not in the middle.
- If there is enough content, do not be stick and overlap the content, just stay at the bottom.
- Hide it from the first sight, so only if the user scrolls down the footer is seen.

This is what worked for me:

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <h1>
      Page
    </h1>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer here
  </footer>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
  min-height:100vh; /*1vh = 1% of browser screen height*/
}

footer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cpeLca18/) in action.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26090114/5802289) goes in the same direction and is much better explained.

Answer (score -3):

Why not with jquery?

Put a wrapper div between header and footer and assign min-height property for wrapper with jquery equal with the difference between document height and (header height + footer height).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var dh = $(document).height(); //document height here
 var hh = $('header').height(); //header height
 var fh = $('footer').height(); //footer height
 var wh = Number(dh - hh - fh); //this is the height for the wrapper
 $('#wrapper').css('min-height', wh); //set the height for the wrapper div
});
</script>
```