# HTML - Footer not at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want the footer be pushed down and appear as last element of the page. However as the content wrapper before has a height of 100%. The content's height exceeds the height of the browser height. In the end the footer appears after the browserheight and not after the content wrapper. How can I change it and still have a 100% height of the wrapper, that is needed for the background design.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogxwXQ)

HTML

```
<div class="content_wrap">
content wrap
<div class="item">content</div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

.content_wrap{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item{
  height: 1300px;
  width: 100%;

      background: red;
}

footer{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the body position property value of relative and position property value of absolute & bottom value of -(footer Height) for the footer

```css
  body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.content_wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.item {
  height: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-100px; /* minus the height of the Footer and it wont overlap any other element */
}
```

```html
<div class="content_wrap">
content wrap
<div class="item">content</div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: I really think this only works if the content is at least 100% of the height of the screen

Comment: Just share the same block of code for HTML and body. It will always remain at the bottom, no matter the height of the content. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zvqq9y8s/ where I reduced the height of the content.

Comment: You've added `html { height: 100% }`. Now it doesn't work anymore if the content is 1300px

Comment: For the content to be salable, make the height of the container auto. if you make it fixed, then the bottom property value of the footer should be minus almost the height of the content container for it not to overlap.

Comment: exactly your example jsfiddle with more content: http://jsfiddle.net/ckuijjer/m3jgvtgL/

Answer (score 1):

```
footer{ position: fixed
        bottom: 0px;
}
```

possible duplicate of: [Bottom footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170452/adding-a-footer-that-is-always-displayed-at-bottom-of-screen)

Comment: but then the footer is visible all the time, that is not wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` on the `content_wrap` it will be at least 100% of the screen in height and it will grow if the content inside it is larger.

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

.content_wrap{
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  border: 2px solid black;
}

.item{
  height: 1300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

footer{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_wrap">
  content wrap
  <div class="item">content</div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    body{
      display:flex;
flex-flow:column;
height:100%;
    }

    header{
      flex:0 0 75px;
    }

    .middle-container{
      display:flex;
flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    footer{
      flex: 0 0 25px;
    }
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="middle-container">
      content wrap
      <div class="item">content</div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
```