# Creating a page footer div?

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, footer, sticky-footer

I need to create a page footer, basically a div that stretch 100% width of the page. With a height of 300px. I need it to stick to the absolute bottom of the page. Could somebody please show me how to do this using CSS?

I have not included code as the code would simply be div tags.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Some css code or anything like, except for simply your `<div>` tags? :P

Comment: Hi - there are a hundred articles on how to do just this. A quick Google is all you need.

Comment: create dive with your given dimention add to css   position:fixed;

Comment: there is a Magic called "CSS" try to google it . . .  :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix footer to bottom of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the footer to position: fixed, it will appear above your content, even if the page is longer than the window.

If what you want is only to keep the footer at the bottom, even when the content is really short, there's that answer : [Sticky footer on Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516910/how-can-i-force-my-footer-to-stick-to-the-bottom-of-any-page-in-css)

That way, your footer will stay at the bottom of the page OR at the end of the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    background-color:red;
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a sticky footer, then you want to use the css position style **fixed**

e.g.

```
div#footer{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
}
```

With this, you would probably also want to set a padding of 300px on the content of the website, so if a user scrolls to the bottom, then they can see the bottom of the content without the footer overlapping it. You would also want to play about with your `z-index` to make sure nothing is appearing infront of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/X9gMD/

This is how the css could look like

```
.footerDiv{
width:100%;
height:300px;
background-color: yellow;
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6HMb/

Simple HTML example:

```
<div id="footer">This a footer text</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer{position:absolute; height:300px; width:100%; bottom: 0%; background-color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position [fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)([`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5HnJg/1/)).

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 2000px;
}

div {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>Footer</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the footer use `position: fixed` CSS property. Something like following shall help.

```
footer.div{
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Hope that helps :)